# How to create image from RGB values in android

Tags: android

i want to create an image from `RGB` values in `android`.

**Exemple of values:** `R=255,G=76,B=87` .

then can you please tell me the steps to create an image from `RGB` values?

Comment: IMAGE or BACKGROUND???

Comment: Don't demonstrate any research effort

Comment: Maybe you should try MS Paint

Comment: nobody is here to answer **how to create?** , but  **how to fix?** ... So try by yourself  : https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=create+image+from+rgb+values+in+java

Comment: You can create a color form those value then set that color to be the background of your view

Comment: It's a very inefficient way to draw an image. Anyway, make a nested loop (outer: y and inner: x) and use setPixel.

Comment: thanks all i have solve this problem by different way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a white color transparent image then convert it into mutable bitmap then change color of bitmap and again set bitmap to imageview.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean that XML drawables. You can check [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html). I mostly use XML drawable

For Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape=["rectangle" | "oval" | "line" | "ring"] >
<corners
    android:radius="integer"
    android:topLeftRadius="integer"
    android:topRightRadius="integer"
    android:bottomLeftRadius="integer"
    android:bottomRightRadius="integer" />
<gradient
    android:angle="integer"
    android:centerX="integer"
    android:centerY="integer"
    android:centerColor="integer"
    android:endColor="color"
    android:gradientRadius="integer"
    android:startColor="color"
    android:type=["linear" | "radial" | "sweep"]
    android:useLevel=["true" | "false"] />
<padding
    android:left="integer"
    android:top="integer"
    android:right="integer"
    android:bottom="integer" />
<size
    android:width="integer"
    android:height="integer" />
<solid
    android:color="color" />
<stroke
    android:width="integer"
    android:color="color"
    android:dashWidth="integer"
    android:dashGap="integer" />
</shape>
```